# How can I click on a link in a dashboard using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm trying to click on the button "Advanced Search" but everything I've tried - referencing by class / xpath etc results in "Element not visible"

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Special Situations Research" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tMA','/maedge/MAIReport.php')">Special Situations Research</a>
</li>
  <li id="tGX" style="z-index:997"><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Governance Exchange" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tGX','/gx/load/')">Governance Exchange</a></li>
  <li id="tVM" style="z-index:996"><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Voting Data" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tVM','/votemetrics/comp/index/')">Voting Data</a>

<ul> 
  <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled"   title="Voting Data" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tVM','/votemetrics/comp/index/')">Companies</a></li>
 <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled"   title="Voting Data" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tVM','/votemetrics/prop/index/')">Proposals</a></li>
 <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled"   title="Voting Data" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tVM','/votemetrics/inst/index/')">Institutions</a></li>
 <li>  <a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled"   title="Voting Data" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tVM','/votemetrics/search/index/')">Search</a></li>
 <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled"  title="Voting Data" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tVM','/votemetrics/shareholder/index/')">Shareholder Resolution Filings</a></li>
</ul></li>

<li id="tSCAS" style="z-index:995"><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="RecoverMax" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=dashboard')">RecoverMax</a><!-- Commented Recovermax menus in Link 1.40 Release to include RecoerMax Dashboard changes

<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Dashboard" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=dashboard')">Dashboard</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="New Cases" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=newCases')">New Cases</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Tentative Settlements" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=tentative')">Tentative Settlements</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Pending Settlements" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=pending')">Pending Settlements</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="International Litigations" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=internationalLitigations')">International Litigations</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Not Yet Disbursed" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=notYetDisbursed')">Not Yet Disbursed</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Disbursements" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=disbursements')">Disbursements</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Claim Tracking" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=claimTracking')">Claim Tracking</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Quick Search" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=quickSearch')">Quick Search</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Advanced Search" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=advancedSearch')">Advanced Search</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Watchlists" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=watchlists')">Watchlists</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Alerts" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=alerts')">Alerts</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink" title="Preferences" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=preferences')">Preferences</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="% Decline Claim Identification" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=percentDeclineClaim')">% Decline Claim Identification</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Eligibility Search" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tSCAS','/scas/index.php?c=index&amp;tabName=eligibilitySearch')">Eligibility Search</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" target="mainDisplay" class="navLink" title="HelpDesk" onclick="parent.location='mailto:scas-help@issgovernance.com';updateBreadCrumb('tSCAS')">HelpDesk</a></li></ul>--></li>
<li id="tECA" style="z-index:994"><a class="navLink unentitled" title="ExecComp Analytics" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tECA','/cda/index.php')">ExecComp Analytics</a>

<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Executive Pay Benchmarking" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tECA','/cda/index.php')">Executive Pay Benchmarking</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled" title="Equity Plan Benchmarking" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tECA','/cda/index.php?c=EquityPlan')">Equity Plan Benchmarking</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="navLink unentitled"  title="Pay for Performance" onclick="updateBreadCrumbNew('tECA','/ngpfp/loadpfp.php')">Pay for Performance</a></li>
```

Would be grateful for help!

Comment: Can you consider showing your work please? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `link_text` or `partial_link_text`? My guess is that you have if you're getting a visibility exception. You'll have to see what you can do to interact with the page to make the element visible (if in fact it isn't).

Comment: can u try this xpath `//ul/li[title='Advanced Search']` and before that use `ExplicitWait` until visibility of element . let me know the conclusion